# Как подключить стиль к тексту?

Tags: css, текст

Подключила в style.css стиль к тексту, но на сайте он не отобраэается. В чем ошибка?

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.promo {
    height: 800px;
    background: url('../img/background/bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
    padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
}

.logo .logo_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
    /* Style for "WordPress" */
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.titile {
    color: #f9bf3b;
    font-family: "Roboto - Black";
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="promo">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="icons/owl.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
                    <div class="logo_text">WordPress интенсив</div>
                </div>

                <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress</h1>
                <div class="simple">
                    <h2 class="title_big">это просто!</h2>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>
            </div>

        </section>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: как должно быть]

[image: как у меня]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто опечатка в названии класса - нужно `.title`, а у вас -`.titile`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.promo {
  height: 800px;
  background: url('../img/background/bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
  padding: 39px 0 62px 0;
}

.logo .logo_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
  /* Style for "WordPress" */
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title {
  color: #f9bf3b;
  font-family: "Roboto - Black";
  font-size: 41px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="promo">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="icons/owl.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
        <div class="logo_text">WordPress интенсив</div>
      </div>

      <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на WordPress</h1>
      <div class="simple">
        <h2 class="title_big">это просто!</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```